# How does function name resolution in CTYPES work?

Tags: python, windows, dll, ctypes, loadlibrary

I am working with a Windows API whose function names start with an underscore in the 32-bit dll (e.g. _FunctionName) but not in the 64-bit version (e.g. FunctionName).

I am using code similar to this to load and call the 64-bit versions of the functions:

```
dll = windll.LoadLibrary('library.dll')
dll['FunctionName']()
```

However, I find that I can also use the same code to call the 32-bit functions even though they start with an underscore. I can even preceed the function name with something other than an underscore and it will still resolve. If I change the name completely then it won't resolve as expected.

I would like to avoid having different ways to call the functions on 64-bit and 32-bit platforms and this seems to work. However, I cannot find any documentation on this behaviour. Can anyone confirm the behaviour or provide documentation for it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C_name_decoration_in_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: Does your 32-bit function name have *only* a leading underscore, or is it a leading underscore *and* a trailing at sign with a number, like `_FunctionName@16`?

Comment: For the 32-bit `stdcall` convention, ctypes first tries `FunctionName` and then loops trying `_FunctionName@n` for n in (0, 4, 8, ..., 124). See [`FindAddress`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.10/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l3172) in _ctypes.c. Something else is going on if the exported name doesn't have an `@n` suffix, and you definitely shouldn't be able to use a prefix "other than an underscore".

Comment: On a related note, the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C_name_decoration_in_Microsoft_Windows) in the above comment is describing a general rule for decorating 32-bit cdecl function names with a leading underscore. However, ctypes follows MSVC, which doesn't use the underscore for C linkage. You can see in `FindAddress` that no attempt is made to decorate the name of a cdecl function (i.e. `FUNCFLAG_CDECL`).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @eryksun that is exactly what I was after. I was mistaken when I said that other prefixes worked - I think it was a compilation issue. It works as you describe now.